# Saving a excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache, file, save

I have written a program to save some data(the data is just four numbers being stored in the String array s[]) into an excel file using apache poi 3.9.
The secondary requirement is to append the data to the same file whenever the program is run. While doing this i notice that the append is successful only when i physically open and save the file every time after program is executed (this is because the row count is being updated only when the file is saved and only an updated row count will facilitate successful append operation) 
So my question is, is there any way to save the file using the program itself ?

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package webcrawler;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;


import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;



/**
 *
 * @author sreekar
 */
public class WebCrawler {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
           try
       {

       int val=0;
       ArrayList <String>addr=new ArrayList<String>();
       addr.add("http://172.26.50.67:8192/0");
       addr.add("http://172.26.50.67:8192/1");
       addr.add("http://172.26.50.67:8192/2");
       addr.add("http://172.26.50.67:8192/3");

       ArrayList <String> files=new ArrayList<String>();
       files.add("C://Users//sreekar//Desktop//node0.xlsx");
       files.add("C://Users//sreekar//Desktop//node1.xlsx");
       files.add("C://Users//sreekar//Desktop//node2.xlsx");
       files.add("C://Users//sreekar//Desktop//node3.xlsx");




             for(val=0;val<addr.size();val++)
             {
                         URL my_url = new URL(addr.get(val));
             System.out.println(my_url);
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(my_url.openStream()));
             String temp=br.readLine();
             Scanner  sc=new Scanner(temp);
                         String [] s=new String[4];
                         for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
                         {
                             s[i]=sc.next();
                         }
             XSSFWorkbook wb = null;
                         XSSFSheet sheet = null;
                         XSSFCell cell=null;
                         XSSFRow row=null;

                         File f=new File(files.get(val));
                         if(f.exists())
                        {
                             FileInputStream input_doc = new FileInputStream(f); 
                             try {
                                 wb = new XSSFWorkbook(input_doc);
                             } catch (IOException iOException) 
                             {
                              iOException.printStackTrace();
                             }
                             sheet=wb.getSheet("node " + val);
                             int rowcount=sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
                             row = sheet.createRow(rowcount++);
                             for (int c=0;c<s.length;c++) {
                                 cell = row.createCell(c);
                                 cell.setCellValue(s[c]);
                             }
                             input_doc.close();

                         }

                        else
                        {
                           int rowcount=0;
                           wb=new XSSFWorkbook();
                           sheet= wb.createSheet("node " + val);
                           row = sheet.createRow(rowcount++);
                           for(int c = 0 ; c < s.length; c++)
                              {
                                cell = row.createCell(c);                    
                                cell.setCellValue(s[c]);
                              }
                        }

                        FileOutputStream out;
                        out = new FileOutputStream(f,true);
                        wb.write(out);
                        out.close();
                    }
           }
        catch (Exception e)
       {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?